# Compare Documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, compare

We are working on an asp.net web application

I need a method to compare two word documents and take out the difference (which will be emailed to a different server) and there need to merge it with the parent document. instead of sending the whole document again and again.

Is there any library available for this ?

Comment: What version of Word are we talking about here ? If it's .docx (i.e. Word 2007 and later) you can use the **OpenXML** sdk to open the docx, and  then you should be able to use the `XMLDiff ` class to compare the two files

Comment: I agree with @SimonRapilly about **OpenXML**.  You should read this post (where OpenXML is suggested): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4796d1fc-831f-4a61-bf63-7db61d1a6b03/can-you-compare-2-word-docs-on-server-using-api-ie-word-not-installed-on-the-server

Comment: hi Simon....thanks...i ended up using google diff patch to create patches and now a dll is created which basically creates a patch for the difference between two files.